# Replace/Override/Overwrite e.target in a JavaScript Event

Tags: javascript, object, mouseevent, prototype

There's a [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8AQM9/32/), can you replace e.target without cloning to a new object?

The listeners from that fiddle are repeated below;

```
one.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // default behaviour, don't modify the event at all
  logTarget(e);
});

two.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // replace the value on the same object, which seems to be read-only
  e.target = document.createElement('p');
  logTarget(e);
});

three.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  function F(target) { 
    // set another property of the same name on an instance object
    // which sits in front of our event
    this.target = target;
  }
  // put the original object behind it on the prototype
  F.prototype = e;
  logTarget(new F(document.createElement('p')));
});

four.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // create a new object with the event behind it on the prototype and
  // our new value on the instance
  logTarget(Object.create(e, {
    target: document.createElement('p')
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8AQM9/33/), as you said, event.target is readonly, but we can overwrite the property descriptor with `Object.create`.

You were on the right way but `Object.create` does not recive only the `key: value` hashmap, it recives `key: property-descriptor` you can see [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) how a property descriptor is.

I've replaced

```
Object.create(e, {
    target: document.createElement('p')
});
```

With

```
Object.create(e, {
    target: {
        value: document.createElement('p')
    }
});
```

And this will prototype `e` and modify the `target` property of the new object.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 51. All properties except for target of the new event object read `[Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at MouseEvent.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)]`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593035/cloning-javascript-event-object for a proper solution.