# How to clone a Javascript Event object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent

This is currently the way I trigger events and it had worked fine for me but now I need to use the event target and I realized it's not being correctly copied:

```
Element.prototype.trigger=function(eventname,ev){
    var e;
    if(ev){
        console.log(ev.target); //target is the element under the mouse
        e = new window[ev.constructor.name](eventname,ev);
    } else e = new Event(eventname);
    this.dispatchEvent(e); //e.target===element
    return this;
}
```

When my function is called, `event.target` is always the same element (it should return the element under the mouse)

```
element.on("mousedrop",function(e){
    console.log("drop",e.target,e.currentTarget); //e.target===element
});
```

How can I clone the event including all of its properties?
This is obviously not a regular object, it wouldn't be recognized as an event and there are some properties with only a getter to just copy them into a new event object.

Here is an example, try to put draggable into droppable:

**https://jsfiddle.net/uxfaprmk/3/**

Comment: Try logging a variable that holds a value instead of a reference, such as `e.target.id`

Comment: That could be an option if I cannot clone the event.

Comment: It's difficult to clone HTML elements.