# Cannot set nested object as default values in the react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set the default values I'm receiving from the API.
Everything works fine except the nested object values - `email` and `phone`

In general form works well when I'm typing the values and submitting them, but not the other way around.

```
const { name, description, contact } = fetchedData;
const { email, phone } = contact;

const { reset } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      name,
      description,
      contact: {
        email,
        phone,
      }
    }
})

useEffect(() => {
    reset({
      name,
      description,
      contact: {
        email,
        phone,
      }
    });
}, [fetchedData]);
```

Comment: Can You add some info about `reset` function? What does this function do? On the first look - I think that problem with destructurization of an object. Better use `Object.assign()`. If you will provide more info i will probably answer better :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably it can problem with destructurization of an object. Destructurization dont do [**deep copy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166214/can-i-use-destructuring-to-create-a-deep-copy) of an object, that why deep fields not copied.

You can try to create a copy with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` and pass it to reset function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ 
        name,
        description,
        contact: { 
          email, 
          phone,
        }
      }
    ))
    reset(deepCopy);
}, [fetchedData]);
```

Comment: Object.assign doesn't do a deep copy, it doesn't go deeper than the first level, unlike helpers like [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Comment: Thank you, I changed solution to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

Comment: @KletskovG unfortunately no luck, I tried to use `useMemo` hook to set the default values as there is some work around with it, but still no luck
`defaultValues: useMemo(() => deepCopy || {}, [deepCopy]),`

Comment: @KletskovG verified the code and there was some additional issue not related to the deep copy. Looks like your suggested solution works as expected. Many thanks!

Comment: @PiotrO Good luck!